# wordpress is saving absolute links and not relative

Tags: wordpress, relative-path, absolute-path

I am developing a wordpress site and I have 3 different environments.
dev, staging and production. each is a different subdomain.

When I export the database to .sql file. I see that the wordpress saves the links like that:
`http://www.mydomain.com/page`
and not
`/page`

it is impossible to go between environments like that. What am I doing wrong?
this is the relevant options from my options table:
`siteurl = http://www.mydomain.com`
`blogname = mydomain.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will save the links relatives to its domain you can read more about here http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

if you are developing a theme just install wordpress in each domain first and them upload the theme you are developing to each of them.
if you want to copy your wordpress to subdomains take a look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress